# Can elastic search provide nested json results?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, solr

I know that **elastic search** provides good support for nested json. It has very good support for `nested objects` with advance indexing.

So, when I make a `nested query` in `elastic search`, can the `query result` be obtained in `original nested form` ? Or is the `query result` in `flattened form` like that in **lucene** or **solr** ?

*Note: I have used apache solr and lucene before. And, I am evaluating other different search platforms for better support for nested json objects.*

Comment: what did you try? yes, in general elastic provides nested hits response

Comment: Sure, results are nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving you a simple example of results maintaining the depth.

> PUT people {   "mappings": {
>       "list": {
>         "properties": {
>           "name": {
>             "type": "nested" 
>           }
>         }
>       }   } }
>
> PUT people/list/1 {   "age" : "19",   "name" : [
>       {
>         "first" : "John",
>         "last" :  "Smith"
>       }   ] }
>
> PUT people/list/2 {   "age" : "23",   "name" : [
>       {
>         "first" : "Wilber",
>         "last" :  "Smith"
>       }   ] }
>
> GET people/list/_search {   "query": {
>       "match_all": {}   } }

As far as I understand, you'll prefer nested mapping to object mapping. Because object would flatten results. See this for reference: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/nested.html